# Event receiver ItemUpdated event doesn't get fired when scheduling is enabled

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

When I manually changed the status of an item in a document library to "Approved", the event receiver's ItemUpdated event got fired. But when I enabled scheduling(to approve an item) to another item, the ItemUpdated event doesn't got triggered. Could anybody please help me on this issue

Comment: Can you please share the scheduling part in details? How you are doing it and everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you use SPD workflow action “update list item” or not to change list item, if you use “set field in current item” to update the item, the event will not be fired. Also, please set the break point in the event receiver project to debug the code, whether the event fired during the operation.

Comment: I have disabled and then uninstalled that feature using powershell and then reinstalled that feature and enabled it, then it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked!